# How to align an SVG inside another element (e.g. anchor)

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple inline SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
<symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <path d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z" />
</symbol>
</svg>

<a href="#"><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#circle" /></svg></a>
```

and some styling:

```
<style>
    .icon{
      fill: black;
      height: 1.25em;
      width: 1.25em;
      display:inline-block;
    }

    a{
      background:red
    }
</style>
```

However in this example, the SVG dimensions are 19.38 x 19.38 (black circle), whereas the anchor is offset and 20 x 17.6 (red background):

[image]

Codepen.io example is here: https://codepen.io/alias51/pen/qBbBoNo.

This is the case whatever the wrapping element around the svg is (`anchor`, `span`, etc). What is going on?? How can I align the SVG and anchor so they are the same dimensions?

Comment: vertical-align: bottom; (or top, or other value .. try and see)

Comment: thanks. I see you closed my question, however the link you provided doesn't answer it. Why are the dimensions different?

Comment: did you read it fully? should be very clear

Comment: 1. the svg element you are using has no width height or viewbox declared 2. I like to give the svg a viewBox and let the svg take the size of the paren Try this:  `.icon{
          display:block;
          fill: black;} a{
          display:block;
          height: auto;
          width: 1.25em;
          background:red;
        }
` Do not forget the viewBox for the svg with the use element `<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 512 512">`